# Filtering for and replacing values in one Pandas DataFrame based on common columns of another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have a question regarding Pandas and the correct indexing and replacing of values.

I have 2 DataFrames, df1 and df2, with the same columns (Col1, Col2, Col3 and Col4).

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['A','b','x',1], ['A','b','y',2], ['A','c','z',3], ['B','b','x',4]], columns=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['A','b','y',0], ['B','b','x',0]], columns=['Col1','Col2','Col3','Col4'])
    
df1
  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
0    A    b    x    1
1    A    b    y    2
2    A    c    z    3
3    B    b    x    4
    
df2
  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
0    A    b    y    0
1    B    b    x    0
```

In **df1**, I would like to replace the values in **Col4** in the rows that match the values of the **other columns** (Col1, Col2 and Col3) in **df2** with another value (let's say 100).

The resulting df1 would look like this:

```
df1
  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
0    A    b    x    1
1    A    b    y  100
2    A    c    z    3
3    B    b    x  100
```

I have tried with something like this:

```
columns = list(df1.columns)    
columns.remove('Col4')
df1.loc[(df1[cols] == df2[cols].values).all(axis=1)]['Col4']=100
```

But I am getting errors and I am not sure if this is even achieving what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do an `isin` with the indices, and assign the value via boolean masking:

```py
cols = ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3']

temp1 = df1.set_index(cols)

temp2 = df2.set_index(cols)

# get the booleans here 
booleans = temp1.index.isin(temp2.index)


# this assigns 100 to only rows in Col4
# that are True
df1.loc[booleans, 'Col4'] = 100

df1

  Col1 Col2 Col3  Col4
0    A    b    x     1
1    A    b    y   100
2    A    c    z     3
3    B    b    x   100
```

Alternatively, you could resolve it with `pd.merge` and the `indicator` parameter:

```py
(df1.merge(df2, 
           on = cols, 
           how = 'left', 
           indicator=True, 
           suffixes = (None, '_y'))
    .assign(Col4 = lambda df: np.where(df._merge == 'both', 
                                       100, 
                                       df.Col4))
   .loc[:, df1.columns]
)

  Col1 Col2 Col3  Col4
0    A    b    x     1
1    A    b    y   100
2    A    c    z     3
3    B    b    x   100
```

Comment: Many thanks! The first solution appears to work up to a point for me. When applying the soltion, the values in Col4 not corresponding to the True values in booleans are replaced by NaNs. So while values in rows 1 and 3 are correctly replaced by 100, values in rows 0 and 2 are incorrectly replaced by NaNs. Otherwise this seems to work very well and is nicely parsimonious. Is there a way to correct this last issue?

Comment: is there any change in the column name? from `Col4` to `col4`? small case? upper case? Do you mind sharing a larger example where NaNs are introduced?

Comment: My bad! That was exactly the issue, you have 'col4' in your last line instead of 'Col4'. Will edit

Comment: my apologies on that

Answer (score 2):

Let's use the `pandas.DataFrame.update` method:

```
df1 = df1.set_index(['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'])
_df2 = df2.set_index(['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'])

# set arbitrary value for Col4
_df2['Col4'] = 100

# update values in df1
df1.update(_df2)

# reset index
df1 = df1.reset_index()
```

Comment: This seems to work very well (although df1 and df2 seem to be swapped in the example; i.e.  would like to update df1 with the values of df2, not the other way around). However, and I did not mention this in my question, this solution changes the order of the rows in the updated df so that the changed rows are on top. I would like to preserve the ordering of the rows. Nonetheless an elegant solution!

Comment: My bad on the df2 mixup, edited the answer.. We could do a `.sort_values()` after we're done to re-order the rows if necessary, but I would otherwise prefer @sammywemmy's solution with the boolean `.loc` assignment, which I think would be faster (performance wise)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```py
new_df =df1.merge(df2, on=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'], how='left', suffixes=(None, '_y'))
new_df.loc[new_df.Col4_y.notna(), 'Col4'] = 100

new_df.loc[:, df1.columns]
```

```
   Col1 Col2    Col3    Col4
0   A    b        x       1
1   A    b        y      100
2   A    c        z       3
3   B    b        x      100
```

I would also like to note the performance of the approach with `merge` and with `isin`

```py
%%timeit
# best answer
cols = ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3']

temp1 = df1.set_index(cols)

temp2 = df2.set_index(cols)

# get the booleans here 
booleans = temp1.index.isin(temp2.index)


# this assigns 100 to only rows in Col4
# that are True
df1.loc[booleans, 'Col4'] = 100
```

```
3.97 ms ± 765 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

```py
%%timeit
cols = ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3']
(df1.merge(df2, 
           on = cols, 
           how = 'left', 
           indicator=True, 
           suffixes = (None, '_y'))
    .assign(Col4 = lambda df: np.where(df._merge == 'both', 
                                       100, 
                                       df.Col4))
   .loc[:, df1.columns]
)
```

```
5.78 ms ± 660 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

```py
%%time
# by kelvt
df1 = df1.set_index(['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'])
_df2 = df2.set_index(['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'])

# set arbitrary value for Col4
_df2['Col4'] = 100

# update values in df1
df1.update(_df2)

# reset index
df1 = df1.reset_index()
```

```
21.46 ms ± 609 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

and

```py
%%timeit
# my answer
new_df =df1.merge(df2, on=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'], how='left', suffixes=(None, '_y'))
new_df.loc[new_df.Col4_y.notna(), 'Col4'] = 100
```

```
1.49 ms ± 109 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

This is important if your df1 and df2 are large enough

Answer (score 0):

You can always Loop through the data frames and replace the value when you get a match

```
for index_df1, row_df1 in df1.iterrows():
    for index_df2, row_df2 in df2.iterrows():
        if (row_df2[:-1] == row_df1[:-1]).all():
            df1.loc[index_df1, 'Col4'] = 100
```

Comment: Always try to avoid iterating the pandas Dataframe in the for loop